# How to show latitude and longitude in map from database in android app

Tags: java, android

> latitude and longitude declared in double
>   error is : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
>   error line is :    LatLng doctors = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

```
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng doctors = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(doctors).title(dName));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(doctors));
    }
```

> fetch data from databse
>   fetch data correctly there has no problem

```
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Json Data is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "http://amitumi.com/public/api/doctor/all";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String lat = c.getString("lat");
                        String lon = c.getString("long");

                        latitude = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(lat));
                        longitude = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(lon));

                        dName = c.getString(name);

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        contact.put("lat", lat);
                        contact.put("long", lon);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems like your latitude and longitude values are null. Debug for those values if those are null. Before using these values in LatLng add a null check. This will help you.

Comment: @Prashant.J you are right. but new error is :  Json parsing error: No value for 23.7443355

Comment: paste the new error and the point where you get it.

Comment: @Prashant.J new error is : Json parsing error: No value for 23.7443355 and there has no point to show

Comment: This is a different error and I think it should because of some json parsing. Your parsing is hampered. Let me post the answer along with that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Check your latitude and longitude values which should be null that is the reason for this error.Also add a null check on these values before using it inside LatLng.

Secondly, Even if it's a different question but still as you mentioned you are getting some parsing error so why don't you use Gson for parsing the response json string. That might help you with this error.
Try it.